# TinyB's CMake script cannot find javah

Tags: cmake, java-10

I tried reinstalling TinyB from scratch: https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb. When I run CMake in Ubuntu

```
cmake -DBUILDJAVA=ON
```

I get this error:

```
INFO - libtinyb Version v0.5.0-dirty
CMake Error at java/CMakeLists.txt:16 (message):
Cannot locate javah executable.


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/tinyb-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/ubuntu/Downloads/tinyb-master/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

My version of Java:

```
java -version
java version "10.0.1" 2018-04-17
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.3 (build 10.0.1+10, mixed mode)
```

What's my problem?

Answer (score 3):

This is an incompatibility of TinyB with Java 10. Please open an issue for TinyB. The reason is, that with Java 10 `javah` is [dropped and replaced](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/10-relnote-issues-4108729.html#JDK-8182758) by `javac` option :

```
-h <directory>
    Specify where to place generated native header files
```

You can try to fix it yourself or use Java 9. Maybe the most recent version of CMake might help; you can give it a try.

TinyB has now an [issue](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb/issues/145) and a [pending merge request](https://github.com/intel-iot-devkit/tinyb/pull/164) regarding this topic.